# System-wide environment variables for QT5

Tags: linux, environment-variables, qt5

**OS**: OpenSuSE TumbleWeed, XFCE 4.14, with HiDPI display, Font size @144DPI

GTK Programs UI are fine.

**Some** QT(5)/KDE Programs UI fonts are HUGE, like (144 * 144/96) DPI that huge, redundantly scaled.

Launch in CLI with 'QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SET_FACTOR=0' like

```
QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SET_FACTOR=0 kate
```

works fine.

But how to set this as default for desktop launcher(Whisker Menu, open text file in Thunar, etc)?

Affected Programs:

kate, keepassxc, KAddressBook, KTnef, KNotes...

Unaffected Programs:

KSuduku, KCalc, KCharSelect...

**Failed** attempts:

- ~/.profile
- /etc/profile
- /etc/environment
- ~/.xinitrc
- QT5ct

Comment: Did you only set the variable in `/etc/profile` or did you also `export` it? Did you try to restart after changing the file?

Comment: exported in `~/.profile` and `/etc/profile`, no need to export in `/etc/environment`. And I can see the variable in CLI shell with `set` or `env`

Comment: Just found out maybe another variable is needed, `QT_SCALE_FACTOR`, waiting for next reboot to confirm.